# Vertically aligning the content of two divs within a table

Tags: html, css

I've got two divs in each td of a table and I'm wanting to vertically centre the text in both of the divs. The two divs don't seem to be able to align independently - i.e. when the second div spans more than one line, the tops of both divs line up. I want the number and the content to be in the middle of the td

HTML:

```
<table class="mytable">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="number">01</div>
        <div class="content"><span>Some extra extra extra long content</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="number"><span>02</span></div>
        <div class="content"><span>Content</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="number"><span>03</span></div>
        <div class="content"><span>Content</span></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
table.mytable td {
    background-color: #276;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
}
.content {
    margin-left: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.number {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/g7xvD/1/)

Comment: `when the second div spans more than one line, the tops of both divs  line up` please explain your desire output

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hogomero/1/edit is this you are looking?

Comment: If you look at the first td in the JSFiddle, you can see that the number is not vertically in the middle of the td. The top of the number div is aligned with the top of the content div

Comment: @user2609051 in MY DEMO 01 is vertically aligned

Comment: Sorry my comment was supposed to come before yours. Yes yours solves the problem thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the divs to `display: table-cell`: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/BGKEz

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

table.mytable td {
    background-color: #276;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
}

td div {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}

.number {width: 40px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="mytable">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="number">01</div>
        <div class="content"><span>Some extra extra extra long content</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="number"><span>02</span></div>
        <div class="content"><span>Content</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="number"><span>03</span></div>
        <div class="content"><span>Content</span></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/g7xvD/19/)**

css

```
table.mytable td {
    background-color: #276;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
}
.content span {
    margin-left: 40px; /* if you wish to keep the margin to the content as in code */
    display: block;
}

table div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; /* this will make the divs behave as table cell and vertical allign will make it in vertical center */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs remove the `float: left;` property from your class `number` and then use `display: table-cell;` property on `div`. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hogomero/1/edit)**.

```
table.mytable td {
  background-color: #276;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mytable div.number, .mytable div.content
{
 display: table-cell; 
 text-align:center; 
 vertical-align:middle;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/*.number {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

See myfiddle

```
.number {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
td:first-child .number{
line-height:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/LMGwH/1/

Answer (score -1):

Why not use different "td" instead of putting two "div" into one cell?

```
 <td>
    <div class="number"><span>03</span></div>
 </td>
 <td>
    <div class="content"><span>Content</span></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Trying this out on the jsFiddle you'll see why they can't do that.